# how to comment xml tag using c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am creating one windows application .which has on comment button.After clicking the comment button "EmbeddedResource include="Lie".licx/" this line should be comes under comment.

```
<Projet>         
 <project group>
    <item group>
      <EmbeddedResource include="Lie".licx/>// <!--<EmbeddedResource include="Lie".licx/>-->
    <item group>
  <project group>
```

Answer (score -1):

Considering you have the bit of XML you want to comment in a string named uncommentedstring:

```
string commentedstring= String.Format("<!--{0}-->",uncommentedstring);
```

This will create a new string which will be `<!--#YOURSTRING#-->`

This will only work if you have your XML as a string, if you have it as a document there are other ways to do it, I'll update my answer if you're more specific.